# PowerShell returns multiple values

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell function, and I want it to return a single Boolean. The problem is that PowerShell will return anything in the pipeline and not just what was explicitly included in the return statement.

Consider the following code.

```
function getTrue(){
  $testVariable = "test"
  $test
  return $true
}

$answer = getTrue

Write-host $answer
```

The output of this code is

```
test True
```

This returns a `System.Object[]`. I want to force the return value to be a `System.Boolean`.

This code works fine if I add a [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host?view=powershell-5.1):

```
function getTrue(){
  $testVariable = "test"
  Write-Host $test
  return $true
}
```

The only problem is that I'm depending on a function that someone else is writing (I can't modify it), and I can't gaurantee that they used a `Write-Host` instead of just leaving the variable on the line by itself.

Is there a way to force the function to only return the value that I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use [`Out-Null`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849716.aspx) to suppress unexpected returning:

```
function getTrue(){
    $test = "test";
    $test | Out-Null;
    return $true;
}

$answer = getTrue
Write-Host $answer
```

and

```
function getTrue(){
    $test = "test";
    Write-Host $test | Out-Null;
    return $true;
}

$answer = getTrue
Write-Host $answer
```